# PCA on Control and treated data for different timepoints with replicates

Tags: r, pca

I am new to PCA, and so I have a confusion. I have a data that has 12 samples of which 6 are control and 6 are treated. there are 2 time-point for each control and treated and 3 replicates for each time-points which makes total 12 samples.

My data looks like this :

```
                           C21 C22  C23 C41 C42 C43 T21 T22 T23 T41 T42 T43
ENSG00000000003        660  451 493 355 495 444 743 259 422 204 149 623

ENSG00000000005           0 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0

ENSG00000000419         978 928 1161 641 810807 1265 361 998 326 239 1055

ENSG00000000457        234 248 444  192 218 326 615 122 395 134 100 406

ENSG00000000460    1096 919 1253 693 907 1185 1648 381 1119 422 269 1267
```

Now I want to carry out PCA on this data, Showing for every gene , the point for control samples and point for treated samples (to calculate the euclidean distance between genes for the control and treated). The first six samples should be taken as control point and the last six samples should be taken as treated.
Note: I need genes to be plotted on the PCA graph for control and treated samples (Not the samples it self).

I did the PCA aready but its takes all the data and gives on one point for each gene, not separate point for control and treated  for every gene. how can I deal with this? Can anybody help?

Answer (score 2):

```
DF <- read.table( text = "   C21 C22  C23 C41 C42 C43 T21 T22 T23 T41 T42 T43
                  ENSG00000000003        660  451 493 355 495 444 743 259 422 204 149 623
                  ENSG00000000005           0 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
                  ENSG00000000419         978 928 1161 641 810 807 1265 361 998 326 239 1055
                  ENSG00000000457        234 248 444  192 218 326 615 122 395 134 100 406
                  ENSG00000000460    1096 919 1253 693 907 1185 1648 381 1119 422 269 1267", header = TRUE)
```

Simply rearrange the input data prior to the PCA. Control and treatment observations should be below each other.

```
DFc <- DF[, 1:6] 
DFt <- DF[, 7:12]

names(DFc) <- gsub("[[:alpha:]*]", "", names(DFc))
names(DFt) <- gsub("[[:alpha:]*]", "", names(DFt))
rownames(DFt) <- paste0(rownames(DFt), "_t")

DF1 <- rbind(DFc, DFt)

summary(pca <- princomp(DF1))

biplot(pca)
```

Note that this answer does not endorse your statistical approach and only answers the programming question.

Comment: Thankyou so much Roland for the answer ! it actually works :)